# Add related list Id to List

Tags: apex, soql, list, childrelationship

I have a SOQL query which gives me the fields i expect:

```
[Select (select Id,Name from signrequest__SignRequests__r) from Lead WHERE Lead.Id='00Q0Y000003iRelUAE']
```

But when i try to place the ids in a list I end up with the lead.ID,

How do I add the innerquery Ids to the List ?

```
List<id> ids = new List<id>();
for(Lead curr:[Select (select Id from signrequest__SignRequests__r) from Lead WHERE Lead.Id='00Q0Y000003iRelUAE']){
  ids.add(curr.id);
  system.debug('ids'+ ids);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following sample code to get your expected output,

Basically you have to simple add the child record id's to the list not parent Id.

```
List<id> ids = new List<id>();
for(Lead curr:[Select (select Id from signrequest__SignRequests__r) from Lead WHERE Lead.Id='00Q0Y000003iRelUAE']){
  for(signrequest__SignRequest__c ss : curr.signrequest__SignRequests__r){
     ids.add(ss.id);
     system.debug('ids'+ ids);
  }
}
```

Hope it help you out !!

Comment: I get an error: Line: 3, Column: 7
Invalid type: signrequest__SignRequests__c

Comment: I found the error signrequest__SignRequests__c should be signrequest__SignRequest__c  Thanks again!!

Comment: it was just typo....Great !!